# Call one parameter after getting it from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to write a query to get one parameter from my model

I used this

```
var ao = db.ApartmentOwners.Where(s => s.phoneNo == phoneNumber).Select(s => new { ID = s.ID });
```

but I am not able to do this `ao.ID` although I tell the query to get just the ID

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Select()` returns `IQueriable` or `IEnumerable` (think of it as of array even if only a row in it), not a single value
To get only the first row use:

```
var ao = db.ApartmentOwners.Where(s => s.phoneNo == phoneNumber).Select(s => new { ID = s.ID }).First();
```

Comment: i used your first query and i got this exception `Sequence contains no elements`

Comment: the second query is not valid, why?

Comment: Empty sequence means no rows mathching your conditions were found. If you not sure whether the row like this exists or not then use .FirstOrDefault() - you'll get default value as a result (null, 0 or anything else according to data type you're selecting from) if row wasn't found, not exception. .First() says "give me the first existing row anyway". Let me check the second expression (probably mistaken, didnt try in VS yet)